# Prove that there exists an isometry P in Isom(H^2) such that P(A)=B

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Where A and B are ideal triangles in H^2 (upper sheet of hyperboloid). How do I get started with this proof?

Comment: To get started, you need to have some supply of isometries of $H^2$.

Comment: Well all of the isometries of H^2 can be written as a matrix in O^+(1,2), right?

Answer (score 0):

This is asssignment question 9.3 here:
http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Teach/2015_MA243/examples9.pdf

Given this, the tags and information given with the question are quite lacking.

**HINT**

All ideal triangles are congruent to each other.